# conditional probabilities general notation

Tags: probability

I have a formula for the probability of some event that contains a lot of terms...

for example

$$\begin{align}
\Pr ~=~& {C_1\cdot\big(\mathsf P(A)\,\mathsf P(D\mid A) + \mathsf P(B)\,\mathsf P(D\mid B) + \mathsf P(C)\,\mathsf P(D\mid C) \big) \\+ C_2\cdot{\big(\mathsf P(A)\,\mathsf P(B\mid A)\,\mathsf P(D\mid A\cap B) + \mathsf P(A)\,\mathsf P(C\mid A)\,\mathsf P(D\mid A\cap C)\\ + \mathsf P(B)\,\mathsf P(C\mid B)\,\mathsf P(D\mid B\cap C)\big)} \\+ C_3\cdot \mathsf P(A)\mathsf P(B\mid A)\,\mathsf P(C\mid A\cap B)\,\mathsf P(D\mid A\cap B\cap C)} \end{align}$$

$C_1, C_2$ etc are constants.

I can see that there is a pattern in this formula in terms of combinatorials... the second line contains terms of the form 
$$
\mathsf P(i)\,\mathsf P(j\mid i)\,\mathsf P(D\mid i\cap j)
$$
where i and j represent all the ways of selecting 2 from a set {A B C} etc

My question is simple (in a sense); is there a concise way to write this formula?

Comment: You can assign to A,B,C some index and then say "for all i,j (...)", i.e. what you did already works :)

Comment: Thanks. That's what I figured but am having a problem with exactly how to write it correctly. I'm guessing with some sort of summation notation...

Comment: perhaps with an index like $$ i ∈ \binom{s}{j} where S = [A, B, C] $$ and $$\binom{s}{2} = [[A,B], [A,C]...]$$ etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the statement a *little* more compact:
$$\begin{align}\Pr ~=~& {C_1\cdot\big(\mathsf P(A)\,\mathsf P(D\mid A) + \mathsf P(B)\,\mathsf P(D\mid B) + \mathsf P(C)\,\mathsf P(D\mid C) \big) \\+ C_2\cdot{\big(\mathsf P(A)\,\mathsf P(B\mid A)\,\mathsf P(D\mid A\cap B) + \mathsf P(A)\,\mathsf P(C\mid A)\,\mathsf P(D\mid A\cap C)\\ + \mathsf P(B)\,\mathsf P(C\mid B)\,\mathsf P(D\mid B\cap C)\big)} \\+ C_3\cdot \mathsf P(A)\,\mathsf P(B\mid A)\,\mathsf P(C\mid A\cap B)\,\mathsf P(D\mid A\cap B\cap C)} \\[2ex] =~& {C_1\cdot\big(\mathsf P(D\cap A) + \mathsf P(D\cap B) + \mathsf P(D\cap C) \big) \\+ C_2\cdot{\big(\mathsf P(D\cap A\cap B) + \mathsf P(D\cap A\cap C) + \mathsf P(D\cap B\cap C)\big)} \\+ C_3\cdot \mathsf P(D\cap A\cap B\cap C)}\\[2ex] =~& {C_1\sum_{X\in\{A,B,C\}}\mathsf P(D\cap X) \\+ C_2\cdot\tfrac 12\sum_{(X,Y)\in\{A,B,C\}^2:X\neq Y}\mathsf P(D\cap X\cap Y)\\+ C_3\cdot \mathsf P(D\cap A\cap B\cap C)}\end{align}$$

For *specific* values of the constants, this becomes a principle of inclusion and exclusion statement:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(D\cap (A\cup B\cup C)) ~=~& {\big(\mathsf P(D\cap A) + \mathsf P(D\cap B) + \mathsf P(D\cap C) \big) \\-{\big(\mathsf P(D\cap A\cap B) + \mathsf P(D\cap A\cap C) + \mathsf P(D\cap B\cap C)\big)} \\+ \mathsf P(D\cap A\cap B\cap C)}\end{align}$$